# jQuery selector to select a text immediate to img tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having the following html code and trying to select text which is located immediate to img tag while clicking the respective img tag.

For example in the first `<p>` tag I should get "**Politics**",

```
 <p>Environmental<img src="/img/bookmark.png" class="bookmark" id="bm1" data-username="usernames" data-userid="un123"> Politics</p>

 <p>Science<img src="/img/bookmark.png" class="bookmark" id="bm2" data-username="usernames" data-userid="un123"> Explore</p>

 <p>Contextual<img src="/img/bookmark.png" class="bookmark" id="bm3" data-username="usernames" data-userid="un123"> Learning</p>
```

I've used the following jQuery function, but nothing helped.

```
$("img.bookmark").click(function(){
   console.log($(this).next());
});
```

Comment: On a side note you should rethink those ids.

Comment: Yupp! Not only that they include spaces (that may even be allowed), they are not even unique (which they have to be). And it looks like they're just storage for something - which is not really the purpose of the ID attribute...

Comment: @PatsyIssa I don't manipulate anything with that ids.

Comment: They still have to be unique. It-#s an requirement for EVERY id, no matter if you use them or not. It's in the HTML spec. Shall I point you to the lines that specify that?

Comment: @JohannesH.Let me edit the ids and make it unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated this *`For example in the first <p> tag I should get "Politics",`*

You can get it with `.nextSibling.nodeValue`:

```
$("img.bookmark").click(function(){
   console.log(this.nextSibling.nodeValue);
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nEtYR/)

Comment: that does give the text as string. if it's not the string that is needed but the text node, get rid of the `nodeValue`. Nice to have answers for both now! (ok,lonesomeday has improved his/her answer, that one now includes both)

Comment: @JohannesH `For example in the first <p> tag I should get "Politics",` i think this is what i tried to show.

Comment: this.nextSibling.value returns all the innerHTML of p tag, but I want to select text after that img tag.

Comment: @Jai: And you're right on this one. The OP just didn't make it clear if it'S the text (as string) or the text node (as DOM Node) what he's looking for.

Comment: its `this.nextSibling.nodeValue` not `this.nextSibling.value`

Comment: nodeValue and value both returns same result such as whole content inside the p tag.

Answer (score 5):

The `next` jQuery function gets the next *element*. You want a text node. You need to use normal DOM traversal methods to get this: you need the [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling) property.

```
$("img.bookmark").click(function(){
   console.log(this.nextSibling);
});
```

You probably actually want its string value, for which you can use `nodeValue`:

```
$("img.bookmark").click(function(){
   console.log(this.nextSibling.nodeValue);
});
```

Comment: this.nextSibling.value returns all the innerHTML of p tag, but I want to select text after that img tag.

Comment: I do. As pointed out in the comments to other answer: it's `nodeValue`, not `value`.

Comment: But not what the OP tried. `this.nextSibling.value returns all the innerHTML` is just not your suggestion ;)

Comment: @JohannesH. Oh, yes, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

```
*nextSibling.data* will give you the text (in your case Politics/../..)


$("img.bookmark").click(function(){
   alert(this.nextSibling.data);
});
```